# Memoryleak when using CFRelease

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, abaddressbook

I have the method which causes a memory leak as shown by the instrument:

[image]

```
-(BOOL)checkIfGroupExistWithName:(NSString*)groupName
{
    BOOL hasGroup = NO;
    //checks to see if the group is created ad creats group for Handheld contacts

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    CFIndex groupCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(ab);
    CFArrayRef allGroups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(ab);

    for (int i=0; i<groupCount; i++) {

        ABRecordRef group = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allGroups, i);

        CFStringRef  CFcurrentGroupName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(group);
        NSString *currentGroupName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFcurrentGroupName;

        if ([currentGroupName isEqualToString:groupName]) {
            //!!! important - save groupID for later use
            groupId = ABRecordGetRecordID(group);
            hasGroup = YES;
            i = (int) groupCount;
        }
        CFRelease(CFcurrentGroupName);
        CFRelease(group);
    }


    return hasGroup;
}
```

If I use  CFRelease(ab); before return hasGroup, it crashes.
I couldn't understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or "Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu) is remarkably good at identifying these issues for you:

[image]

Bottom line, the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) dictates that you have to `CFRelease` any objects returned from Core Foundation functions with either `Copy` or `Create` in their name (except those that you transfer ownership with either `CFBridgingRelease` or `__bridge_transfer`, as that allows ARC to clean those up for you).

Needless to say, you shouldn't `CFRelease` anything else (such as `group`, which was returned by an function without `Copy` or `Create` in the name, nor `CFcurrentGroupName`, which you already transferred ownership with `__bridge_transfer`).

Anyway, you end up with something like:

```
- (BOOL)checkIfGroupExistWithName:(NSString*)groupName {
    BOOL hasGroup = NO;
    //checks to see if the group is created ad creats group for Handheld contacts

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
    if (!ab) {
        NSLog(@"%@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
        return false;
    }

    CFIndex groupCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(ab);
    CFArrayRef allGroups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(ab);

    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {

        ABRecordRef group = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allGroups, i);

        NSString *currentGroupName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(group));

        if ([currentGroupName isEqualToString:groupName]) {
            //!!! important - save groupID for later use
            groupId = ABRecordGetRecordID(group);
            hasGroup = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allGroups) CFRelease(allGroups);
    CFRelease(ab);

    return hasGroup;
}
```

I suspect that your attempt to `CFRelease(ab)` was crashing for other reasons (e.g., `ab` was `NULL` because `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` failed, perhaps you neglected to add `NSContactsUsageDescription` to your plist; `ab` was released before subsequent references to `ab`; you were releasing things you shouldn't have; you received `NULL` from some Core Foundation function and tried to `CFRelease` that; etc.). But the above should work fine as it fixes the aforementioned issues.

Clearly, if using iOS 9 and later only, you can use the Contacts.framework and avoid all of these bridging annoyances altogether.